# Is it possible to use two network card on one PC to use one for Receive and the other one for Send to reduce network overhead?

Tags: network-programming, mpi

I'm working on my project using MPI(Message Passing Interface).
Briefly, what i am doing is dividing a 3 dimensional matrix into n pieces and distribute them to calculate faster.
During the process, nodes have to communicate to get another node's calculating result.
communicating overhead became an issue in regards to speed up.

So, Is it possible to use two network card on one PC to use one for Receive and the other one for Send to **reduce network overhead**?

Or, Could you give me any alternative to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

PS. I am not familiar posting on English. Please be generous and understand.

Comment: Doable for sure. You thinking that each PC in your cluster would have two NICs? Have you determined for sure that your network card is reading and writing at max bandwidth of card? Otherwise your only option, if communication becomes the bottleneck, is to decrease the # of subdivisions of your matrix until you balance the two bottlenecks (CPU and comms).

Answer (score 1):

You can perform NIC Teaming on your PC, but you will require a network switch capable of link aggregation (LACP). Most business-class switches support link aggregation, which you will need to acquire and configure with your PC.